# Calling finish() in Activity Containing two fragments both performing Async Task cant destroy and stop the async task

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous

Am having an activity which contains two fragments both performing async task, when Back button is pressed, i call finish() so that it can end the activity and its fragments. But this does not work and makes the app crash because the async task is still running.

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


            finish();

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Am using the above code to finish all other activities which does not contain fragments and it works fine

Comment: @PedroAGSantos i wish to show codes but it is very long, to my surprise am using the same finish() in Activities which does not contain Fragments and it works fine

Comment: Do you use a property declared in your Activity and/or Fragment in the AsyncTask?

Comment: @Remy I dont use any property declared in the AsyncTask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `finish()` the method `onDestroy()` will then be called, from there you should check to see if those async tasks are still running, if so, cancel them as such

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (getAsyncTaskObject() != null
            && getAsyncTaskObject().getStatus() != Status.FINISHED)
        getAsyncTaskObject().cancel(true);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the function cancel(true) of AsynTask. When you call this function, after AsyncTask finish doingInBackground(...) it will enter onCancelled() instead of onPostExecute(...). To make AsyncTask stop asap, you should check is task canceled periodically from doingInBackground(...) by function isCancelled().